# Laravel: File Download

Tags: laravel, download

I have a download script like this:

```
    public function downloadSampleCSV(){
        $file = public_path()."/downloads/Payout example file.csv";
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/csv',);
        return Response::download($file, 'Payout example file.csv',$headers);
    }
```

The file path is correct and the Network panel even outputs the content of the file, but the file doesn't actually get downloaded from the browser.

Here's what the Network panel shows. You can tell it's found the file but just doesn't proceed to downloading it:
[image: Network panel]

What could be the issue?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in you network tab or console? What does happen when you try and hit that route? Are you just using a link to hit that route, or are you using something like `axios` or `fetch`?

Comment: @Rwd, I've edited the question to show there aren't any error in the network tab. When I click the button that runs the ```downloadSampleCSV``` method nothing happens. It's just a button that hits the above method, but nothing is downloaded - it just loads ```downloadSampleCSV``` in the network tab; as you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: From the looks of things, you're trying to download it using ajax. Are you using a Livewire or just javascript for this? If it's javascript, please can you update your question with that code and the HTML as well.

Comment: @Rwd, my goal was to download via GET not via AJAX. How would I go about that>

Comment: Please can you show your javascript and HTML.

Comment: What triggers the download? If it's a link then you could add the ```download``` prop and href to the file path directly in the front end. But if you have to go via the backend, have you tried adding the attachment header? ```"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Payout example file.csv"``` and make sure it's an ASCII file name

Comment: @justrusty, what triggers it is a button. I'm using a template called Orchid, so the button looks like this and it calls the ```downloadSampleCSV()``` method: 

```Button::make('Download Template ')->method('downloadSampleCSV')```

Comment: @Rwd, I used a template called Orchid and all the code is in PHP. The button I click is also written in PHP and not an anchor tag (See comment above @justrusty).

Answer (score 0):

allows file downloads with response()->download() to return file for download. We no longer need to mess with any headers. To return a file we simply:

```
return response()->download(public_path('/downloads/Payoutexamplefile.csv'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to do with the Orchid template itself and how it handles AJAX. You're supposed to add `->turbo(false)` to the button.

So, the button should look like this:

```
Button::make('Download Template ')
 ->method('downloadSampleCSV')
 ->turbo(false),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was using Livewire. To solve this problem I changed my approach. I made a Laravel Controller and a Route and then in my Blade file requested this Route.

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class FileDownload extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $fileName = $request->fileName;
        $filePath = public_path() . "/downloads/" . $fileName;
        return Storage::disk('local')->download($filePath);       
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/file/download/{fileName}', App\Http\Controllers\FileDownload::class)->name('file-download');
```

Blade:

```
<a href="{{ route('file-download', ['fileName' => 'Your file name can be loaded dynamically' }}">Download</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

Why you are not using this in your blade file?
`<a href="{{ asset('/downloads/Payout example file.csv') }}" download> Download File </a>`